# Linq First Item

Tags: c#

I have a Linq statement which concats three `list`s together:

```
var FinshedResults = QualificationList.Zip(SubjectList, (x, y) => x + y).Zip(GradeList, (x, y) => x + y);
```

The out put this is giving me is:

```
A Level - Test 1 (A*) A Level - Test 2 (A) A Level - Test 3 (B) A Level - Test 4 (C) A Level - Test 5 (D) A Level - Test 6 (E) A Level - Test 6 (E) A Level - Test 7 (F)
```

The A Level is stored in `QualificationList` I was just wondering whether we can make it so A - Level is printed out once and the rest have Test 1 etc. So the out put would more be like;

```
A Level - Test 1 (A) Test 2 (A) Test 3 (B) Test 4 (C) Test 5 (D) Test 6 (E) Test 6 (E) Test 7 (F)
```

Is it possible to make `QualificationList` only print out once? Or would this have to be handled in the loop? Thanks for any advice which you can give.

Comment: How are qualifications linked to grades? Seems like all you are doing here is appending strings together.

Comment: Please add some more details. You are using some thinking shortcuts that are clear only to you. Lists don't print, and what you do doesn't look like "concatenation of lists". Show how are you using this code, with what input data.

Comment: The are appended by a stringbuilder when looping through the linq statement FinshedResults

Comment: @willa Don't describe code with words :) Show the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
QualificationList
.GroupBy(x => x)
.SelectMany(g => new[] { g.Key }.Concat(Enumerable.Repeat("", g.Count() - 1))
.Zip(SubjectList, (x, y) => x + y)
.Zip(GradeList, (x, y) => x + y);
```

I'm assuming `QualificationList` is a list of strings. This query simple groups `QualificationList` and then returns a sequence of elements for each group where the first element is the `Key` (for example A Level) the rest is an empty string. Then just uses `Zip` like you did, the only difference is rest of the elements are concatenated with empty string so the `A Level` won't appear more than once.

Comment: Have you tested this code? It does not yield the correct results.

Comment: @James no,I haven't, what does it yield ?

Comment: A single result - `A LevelTest 1(A)`

Comment: Actually, apologies my test was wrong. It gives more or less the correct results (the first result is still the one mentioned previously though).